# iOS layout pass and constraints update

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

From the apple documentation, under the deferred layout pass, it says

***'Instead of immediately updating the affected views’ frames, Auto Layout schedules a layout pass for the near future. This deferred pass updates the layout’s constraints and then calculates the frames for all the views in the view hierarchy.'***

What is really baffling is the term "near future".

The function `setneedsLayout()` signals that you want to redraw a view and all of its subviews, when it is time for an update cycle, but why even bother calling this function when you don't even know when the update cycle will happen? shouldn't we just use `layoutIfNeeded()` all the time so that we can say in our heads that "right, I want this view to be updated now, so I'll use `layoutIfNeeded()`. Also, is there any other uses of `layoutIfNeeded()` other than using it in `UIView.animateWithDuration()`?

I've been reading a lot of article and the concept still hasn't really stick yet, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call the `setNeedsLayout()` directly most of the time. When you make a change to a `UIView` it will *automatically* call `setNeedsLayout`. When you update constraints in Auto Layout it will send the **deferred pass** message to the affected `UIView`s that it will need to that they need to layout as well. This will *mark* the view as needing to layout it's subviews. You can  layout the view at a certain time by calling the `layoutIfNeeded()` function. This will execute and layout the subviews as required.

As you asked, there are many more uses to called the `layoutIfNeeded()` function without calling it inside an animation block.

For a simple example, maybe you don't want to use animations at all, and just want to layout your constraints.

```
subview.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50) 
// Above makes change to the view. 'setNeedsLayout()' has been called

// Below will layout immediately
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

To answer you question about the "near future" portion, I am not entirely sure. An educated guess would be that because all of the affected `UIView`s in the layout change have to be informed to layout at a certain time that would mean they would also need to calculate their new frames. Depending on the amount of `UIView`s that invoke the `setNeedsLayout()` function there could be some significant processing time involved. And that maybe be why they say in the "near future".

Comment: Thank you the response, so does that mean that whenever I programmatically change a constraint (say the change is made when you tap a button) on a UIView, both `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded` will be called and the view size and position will be updated automatically? but when we change the actual frame of the UIView, you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` in order to see the change? thanks

Comment: No, `setNeedsLayout()` will be called but **you** will need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` yourself to apply the layout that `UIView` marked as needing to layout. `layoutIfNeeded()` is what makes the change happen on screen and you can use in an animation block to animate the layout change or just call it like in my example above and it will just set the layout immediately. The "if needed" part of the method name refers to the possibility that `setNeedsLayout()` was never called because there may not have been an update to the`UIView`, in which case layout is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, okay. But to your point, I tried this on a project and I basically have a UIButton and a UILabel, When I tap the button, it changes one of the constraint of the UILabel. When I run and build it, as soon as I tapped on the button, the UILabel shifts **without** calling `layoutIfNeeded()`. Following your logic, the UILabel shouldn't have changed because although `setNeedsLayout()` is called, but without calling `layoutIfNeeded()`, the positional change of the UILabel **should not have happened**

Comment: Yes that is because you used a constraint and when you update a constraint it will do it's equivalent of `setNeedsLayout()` and it will make the call to layout its view on the next update cycle. To learn more about this take a read of this article: http://www.iosinsight.com/setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-explained